# Format UITextfield from UIPicker that has 5 components?

Tags: iphone, xcode, format

I have 1 UIPicker with 5 components, all numbers 1-9. I just want all 5 components to show up in the UITextfield. I have a feeling there is a much shorter code for this than what I have:

```
NSString *result = [metricMillimeterArray objectAtIndex:[metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:0 & [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]& [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:2]& [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:3]& [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:4]]];
```

Comment: What does this mean - 'I just want all 5 components to show up in the UITextfield." ? Get the value from those components and assign it to your cell as a string ? If so, then *THUMBS UP*. This is good. Dont assign result twice.

Comment: First of all the "&" does not concatenate items.  In this case it logically ANDs them together!  The %d expects an integer value.  Are you trying to build a 5 digit numeric from a 5 component UIPicker?

Comment: @trumpetlicks Yes, I just have 5 rows 1-9 and want them to show up 12345. Right now I'm getting a longer string than I should be, and it's not getting the right values.

Comment: @Legolas I can't seem to get it to display right..can you help?

Comment: Look at the answer I provided, does this help?

Comment: @trumpetlicks I replied that it is giving errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what your objects are that are returned, but if

```
[metricMillimeterArray objectAtIndex:[metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]
```

commands return strings (that are one character long) then you will need to:

```
result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d mm", 
    10000 * [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] + 
    1000 *  [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:1] + 
    100 *   [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:2] +
    10 *    [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:3] + 
            [metricMillimeterPicker selectedRowInComponent:4] ];
```

This is assuming that your component 4 is your least significant, but the powers of 10 can be swapped if that part I got wrong.

Comment: Getting Error
"Expected ':'"
on all 5 of your lines?

Comment: Errors, Use of undeclared identifier intValue

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be a shorter way that worked! Thanks!